# Caffe: resuming from a trained snapshot fails with an error

Tags: snapshot, caffe, pre-trained-model, resuming-training

I trained my network with some configuration , and then saved a snapshot of it.
Now I am trying to resume from the last snapshot and it fails with this error message :

```
I0328 13:44:30.756110 24238 net.cpp:283] Network initialization done.
I0328 13:44:30.756206 24238 solver.cpp:60] Solver scaffolding done.
I0328 13:44:30.757062 24238 caffe.cpp:209] Resuming from /media/hossein/tmpstore/caffe_new/examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_bn_iter_60000.caffemodel.h5
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.15-patch1) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 358 in H5Dopen2(): not found
    major: Dataset
    minor: Object not found
  #001: H5Gloc.c line 430 in H5G_loc_find(): can't find object
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #002: H5Gtraverse.c line 861 in H5G_traverse(): internal path traversal failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
  #003: H5Gtraverse.c line 641 in H5G_traverse_real(): traversal operator failed
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Callback failed
  #004: H5Gloc.c line 385 in H5G_loc_find_cb(): object 'iter' doesn't exist
    major: Symbol table
    minor: Object not found
F0328 13:44:30.786376 24238 hdf5.cpp:153] Check failed: status >= 0 (-1 vs. 0) Failed to load int dataset with name iter
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f2d6e635daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f2d6e635ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f2d6e6356e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f2d6e638687  (unknown)
    @     0x7f2d6ed74acd  caffe::hdf5_load_int()
    @     0x7f2d6ed678d0  caffe::SGDSolver<>::RestoreSolverStateFromHDF5()
    @     0x7f2d6ed4bf19  caffe::Solver<>::Restore()
    @           0x408038  train()
    @           0x405a0c  main
    @     0x7f2d6d943ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x406141  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This is how I'm trying to resume it :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TOOLS=./build/tools

$TOOLS/caffe train \
    --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_solver_bn_lr2.prototxt \
    --snapshot=/media/hossein/tmpstore/caffe_new/examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_bn_iter_60000.caffemodel.h5
```

I then gave up, and I tried to use `BINARYPROTO` instead of `HDF5`, but I get this error :

```
I0328 16:35:34.721277 27243 net.cpp:283] Network initialization done.
I0328 16:35:34.721369 27243 solver.cpp:60] Solver scaffolding done.
I0328 16:35:34.722338 27243 caffe.cpp:209] Resuming from /media/hossein/tmpstore/caffe_new/examples/cifar10_full_relu_bn_iter_60000.caffemodel
F0328 16:35:39.143900 27243 sgd_solver.cpp:316] Check failed: state.history_size() == history_.size() (0 vs. 28) Incorrect length of history blobs.

*** Check failure stack trace: ***

    @     0x7fd1c2cbbdaa  (unknown)
    @     0x7fd1c2cbbce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7fd1c2cbb6e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7fd1c2cbe687  (unknown)
    @     0x7fd1c33ef097  caffe::SGDSolver<>::RestoreSolverStateFromBinaryProto()
    @     0x7fd1c33d1ed3  caffe::Solver<>::Restore()

    @           0x408038  train()
    @           0x405a0c
 main
    @     0x7fd1c1fc9ec5  (unknown)

    @           0x406141  (unknown)
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

when I tried different times with different models , the history part changes ( like 58 vs 28, 32 vs 28 for example and like this, the over all error is the same, the number differs though!)

What should I do? this is making me crazy!

Comment: regarding the hdf5 format: I had the same issue. I went back to binaryproto. I guess there's still some work to be done on exporting/importing hdf5 weights

Comment: What about the second part which pertains to the binaryproto format? I cant figure it out :-/

Comment: sorry, dis not come across this one...

Comment: @Shai: Thanks buddy ;)

Comment: one of the reasons that I found, was caffe ha a bug with Adam and AdaDelta types. 
and I encountered this error whenever I had a solver with AdaDelta.

Comment: I have the same problem now...using SGD and hdf5..don't know how to fix this..it works fine when I load the network in python...only training is not working

Comment: @Tarun: You should create an issue and see if its really a bug like in my case or some weird reason is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the value for the --snapshot argument, you have to pass the .solverstate.h5 file, not the .caffemodel.h5 file.